# High IO rate when system out of memory

Tags: linux, memory, memory-usage

I found that when the system goes out of memory, the disk IO usage will be very high.

It seems many processes are **reading** from hard disk frantically (check `htop` output below).
When I kill a process that use too much memory, free some memory for system. The IO usage decreases to a normal state.

The problem can be reproduced by writing a program that consumes a lot of memory until there is not enough memory on machine. When you killed that running program, everything goes back to normal.

**I am aware of the os mechanism of swap. But it seems the swap was not even used for the whole time** (check `free` and `vmstat` output below).

```
❯ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          859Mi       692Mi        60Mi        25Mi       106Mi        36Mi
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

```
❯ htop
PID   RES   SHR CPU% MEM%   TIME+    DISK READ  DISK WRITE    DISK R/W Command
 6386 37316  5380  0.7  4.2 10:40.07   14.96 M/s    0.00 B/s   14.96 M/s ahdbserver-1.3.2-SNAPSH
23252 17880 15748  0.0  2.0  0:01.24    7.91 M/s    0.00 B/s    7.91 M/s postgres -D /var/lib/po
29428   400     0  0.0  0.0  0:02.63    3.36 M/s    2.63 K/s    3.36 M/s sgagent -d
 2369  197M     0  0.0 23.0  0:01.00    1.86 M/s    0.00 B/s    1.86 M/s java -jar memtest-1.0-S
24596 10820     0  0.0  1.2  0:59.53  694.74 K/s    0.00 B/s  694.74 K/s frps -c frps.ini
22901  122M     0  2.0 14.2  1:15.23  644.74 K/s    0.00 B/s  644.74 K/s srcds_linux -game dod -
 8735  2016    52  0.7  0.2  1:46.21  344.74 K/s    0.00 B/s  344.74 K/s htop
 2959  4664   176  0.0  0.5 15:35.06  318.42 K/s    0.00 B/s  318.42 K/s tmux
23265 18160 14344  0.0  2.1  0:01.30  286.84 K/s    0.00 B/s  286.84 K/s postgres: 11/main: post
23264  7036  3992  0.0  0.8  0:00.03   78.95 K/s    0.00 B/s   78.95 K/s postgres: 11/main: Time
23262  7160  4116  0.0  0.8  0:00.04   71.05 K/s    0.00 B/s   71.05 K/
```

```
❯ vmstat 2
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  0      0  68588   2096 103156    0    0 28436     0 1787 4288  2  8 79 12  0
 0  1      0  57564    920 115364    0    0 24604    86 1676 3811  2  4 81 14  0
 0  0      0  70252   1156 102360    0    0 31750     0 1794 4337  3  8 75 15  0
 1  0      0  68632   2776 101380    0    0 38570    16 2139 4879  2 11 67 19  0
 0  0      0  67656    892 104940    0    0 29356    14 1706 3936  3  5 77 15  0
 0  0      0  68596    372 103368    0    0 50684     0 2324 5078  3 11 70 16  0
 0  0      0  69596    268 102512    0    0 35688    38 1890 4282  2  8 76 15  0
 0  1      0  69368    172 102540    0    0 35726    54 1877 4458  2  9 71 19  0
 0  1      0  69684   1912 100916    0    0 28724     0 1759 4235  3  7 74 16  0
 0  0      0  74380    768  97076    0    0 21198     0 1484 3762  2  5 80 13  0
```

```
❯ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

What are the reasons?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to run the `perf top`.

Comment: I've been chasing similar issues for a while now. At first I assumed it was thrashing but there is no paging activity, but huge block input counts. I find it hard to believe it's insufficient cache, as the system still has over 2 GiB of cache, but suddenly many processes are busy doing disk reads (that previously weren't). `perf top` shows over 10% time in page_vma_mapped_walk.

Answer (score 5):

When memory usage increases, the available (free) memory for cache and buffers decreases. With less cache memory more data must be loaded from disk, because it is uncached.

This will, of course, lead to more i/o activity.

Answer (score 0):

Just to rephrase Andreas Rogge answer.

Due to low memory, the filesystem cache is too small and permanently invalidated. This increases the load on  IO subsystem,  as any  request passed to disks.